# Oracle: remove duplicates from select results in specific columns

Tags: oracle

I need to create a view contains BSB#, customer#, name from customer, and account#, type, balance from account.
I tried this select statement:

```
select customer.bsb#, customer.customer#, customer.name, account.account#, account.type, account.balance
from customer
left outer join account on customer.bsb# = account.bsb#
and customer.customer# = account.customer#;
```

And the output is like this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAv5n.png)
However, I need to make the out like:
[display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfhVj.png)
So, how could I remove the duplicate results from certain columns?

Comment: You should do this in your application code

Comment: it is [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851819/sql-oracle-display-values-only-once-per-column). see this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29851970/7837926 basically it is [windows analitic function](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23sql-1906475.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Oracle - display values only once per column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851819/sql-oracle-display-values-only-once-per-column)